# Wordpress keeps adding -2 to permalinks

Tags: php, xml, wordpress, custom-post-type

I'm currently building an object listing for a realtor and we are caching all the objects locally in a custom post type called "objekt", and it has the permalink rewrite "objekt".

We have a file in the root of the server called `wp-fetch-items.php` which the realtors application pings at the time of a new object in the system. This causes all posts of the type "objekt" to be deleted, and then it goes through an XML-file and adds all the objects to the system again.

Everything works perfectly fine, but the posts keep getting -2 in the URL, even if it's the first time the post is created, and there is nothing with a name even remotely similar.

For instance, an object which I insert using `wp_insert_post` with the name `152912` gets the post_name of `152912-2`.

I create the objects with the following code:

```
$insertedPost = wp_insert_post(array(
    'post_author' => 1,
    'post_type' => 'objekt',
    'ping_status' => 'closed',
    'post_status' => 'publish',
    'post_name' => $objectData['title'],
    'post_title' => $objectData['title']
), false);
```

And before they are created, I loop through every post with the type "objekt" and remove them using this code:

```
wp_delete_post(get_the_ID(), true);
```

I specifically added true as a second parameter to permanently remove the object from the database and all searches I do prove that there is nothing left of it.

I also tried flushing the permalinks after deletion using this code, but it does nothing to help the situation:

```
global $wp_rewrite;
$wp_rewrite->flush_rules();
```

Have you experienced this issue, and do you know how to solve it? Please reply if you know what could be causing this!

Thanks in advance,
Jonathan

Comment: Go into your permalinks setting and see if that 2 has been added. If so, delete it. Has happened to a couple of my blogs.

Comment: in addition, I would also check the .htaccess file just to make sure nothing there are no rewrite rules dictating the problem.

Comment: Hello, thanks for the answer. I've checked the permalink setting, and it's currently set to "/%year%/%monthnum%/%day%/%postname%/". No matter what changes I do the post still gets the same name. I tried removing all rules in the .htaccess, but to no avail.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Wordpress has a special handling of numerical post names. This is intentionally, because it assumes that a numerical ID in the URL is the actual ID of the post. Adding the `-2` makes sure that it is interpreted as a string and as such as the name of the post. Otherwise it would try to show `http://yoursite/?p=152912` and result into a 404 if this post id doesn't exist.

The only solution I found so far: avoid numerical names.

(I wrote post because internally everything is a post, even pages and images)

**edit:**

I found the [ticket that introduced this behaviour](http://core.trac.wordpress.org/ticket/11917).

Answer (score 0):

Check that you don't already have a post with that permalink. If the permalink already exists on that post, WordPress will append `-2` to the permalink. Check your trash too.

Comment: Thanks for the response, although the post above yours was correct.